# How to have a Praw Script watch multiple streams simultaneously

Tags: python, praw

I have a redditbot that needs to take an action if it is sent a message, or if a certain subreddit recieves a post with a certain title. I would like to not run two different python scripts in the background of my computer simultaneously (one watching the bots inbox, one watching the bots designated subreddit). Is there a way to combine multiple streams into one?

Something like:

```
for post, msg in reddit.inbox.strea() or subreddit.posts.stream():
     do msg action
     do post action
```

Here is the two peices of code I'm trying to combine into one stream:

## 1

```
for msg in reddit.inbox.stream(skip_existing = True):
    if msg == 'all':
        all_repots()
    else:
        report(msg)
```

## 2

```
subs = reddit.subreddit('SomeSubreddit')


status = str('This is my status!')




for post in subs.stream.submissions():
    if 'botname' and 'report!' in post.title:
        post.reply(status)
```

Comment: You could run two threads as part one application

Comment: (I’m a novice, so forgive me if this sounds foolish) I’m just using scripts that I plan to run on my comp, and would prefer if there was only one script to start and stop. I’m not using an application. (Is that an ignorant answer?)

Comment: When you say "script", it's the same as when I say "application". Threading is a Python library, it should work fine when using praw, or other libraries

Comment: I'll check it out! Thanks!

Comment: Turns out PRAW is not thread safe for the same instance /: and I need each thread to have the same credentials

Comment: Check this out: https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/7vj6ox/can_i_do_other_things_with_praw_while_reading/dtszfzb/